# How to proper track record changes and the author of the changes

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE car
(
    car_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,

    created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    PRIMARY KEY (car_id)
);
```

To audit data changes on this table I'm creating a history table. By using triggers the history table will have an entry for each insert, update and delete query executed on the original table. The structure of the history table is the same as the table it tracks except for 2 additional columns, a column to store the operation that occurred and a column to store a sequence number. I have been using this solution for a long time now, mostly because it is painless to implement and requires little to no effort to maintain.

The following script generates the SQL needed to implement these history tables in a database if:

1. the tables do not start with _ (because the history tables will do);
2. the tables have a non composite primary key;
3. the tables don't have columns named action and revision.

The SQL:

```
SELECT
    'CREATE TABLE __' || table_name || ' LIKE ' || table_name || ';\r\n' ||
    'RENAME TABLE __' || table_name || ' TO _' || table_name || ';\r\n' ||
    'ALTER TABLE _' || table_name || ' ADD action TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL FIRST;\r\n' ||
    'ALTER TABLE _' || table_name || ' ADD revision INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL FIRST;\r\n' ||
    'ALTER TABLE _' || table_name || ' MODIFY ' || column_name || ' ' || UPPER(data_type) || IF(is_nullable = 'NO', ' NOT NULL', '') || ';\r\n' ||
    'ALTER TABLE _' || table_name || ' DROP PRIMARY KEY;\r\n' ||
    'ALTER TABLE _' || table_name || ' MODIFY COLUMN revision INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;\r\n' ||
    'CREATE TRIGGER i' || table_name || ' AFTER INSERT ON ' || table_name || ' FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO _' || table_name || ' SELECT NULL, 1, ' || table_name || '.* FROM ' || table_name || ' WHERE ' || table_name || '.' || column_name || ' = NEW.' || column_name || ';\r\n' ||
    'CREATE TRIGGER u' || table_name || ' AFTER UPDATE ON ' || table_name || ' FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO _' || table_name || ' SELECT NULL, 2, ' || table_name || '.* FROM ' || table_name || ' WHERE ' || table_name || '.' || column_name || ' = NEW.' || column_name || ';\r\n' ||
    'CREATE TRIGGER d' || table_name || ' BEFORE DELETE ON ' || table_name || ' FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO _' || table_name || ' SELECT NULL, 3, ' || table_name || '.* FROM ' || table_name || ' WHERE ' || table_name || '.' || column_name || ' = OLD.' || column_name || ';'
FROM information_schema.tables
JOIN information_schema.table_constraints USING (table_schema, table_name)
JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage USING (table_schema, table_name, constraint_name)
JOIN information_schema.columns USING (table_schema, table_name, column_name) 
WHERE
    information_schema.tables.table_schema = (SELECT DATABASE()) AND
    information_schema.table_constraints.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY';
```

Now I have a new business rule that is slightly breaking my model. Each row needs to hold the author_id, meaning the user who made the last change on the data, so I'm adding the author_id column to the car table and to the history table that tracks its changes. This is a problem because when a user deletes a row the author of that change will be lost. I have found 3 solutions for this problem:

1. update the author_id column before deleting the row.

I don't like this solution because it creates extra rows in the history table. Also, it adds extra logic to every delete routine.

2. delete the row and update the author_id directly in the history table, based on the last inserted id.

It is possible to make this work without adding extra code to the delete routines but directly accessing the history tables sounds like a big no for me (eventually these tables will be very big).

3. logical delete instead of physical delete.

Logical vs physical delete is a decision to be made based on the data and the business requirements, not to fix a caveat on the model.

**Which solution do you think is best? Why? Is there another solution for this problem?**

Answer (score 1):

You should consider getting your `DELETE` triggers to insert new rows to the history tables memorializing each delete operation. That history row can carry the `author_id` of the author deleting the main-table row.

Using a logical delete -- tagging each deleted row as inactive -- is also a good way to go.  It's a common approach to handling obsolete rows. You can conceal the logically deleted rows from your application logic with an appropriate view on each table.

At any rate, you shouldn't ever update a row in a history table. Instead you should insert a new row for each event you want to record. If you do that, you will improve the integrity of your history. You don't have to grant the `UPDATE` priv on the table. You can use the cheap [ARCHIVE storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/archive-storage-engine.html). And, if your main table has some kind of financial value, your auditors will sing your praises.

Prof. Richard Snodgrass wrote a fine book [Developing Time-Oriented Database Applications in SQL](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~rts/publications.html), and has made it available online. It has lots of good ideas about how to handle this sort of information.

Comment: Nice input, thanks, specially for the article. I will wait a few more days hoping someone finds a little magic in there and fix my model before starting to rewrite every delete routine. Also, i can't make my mind between 1 and 3, both solutions look shitty.